# ILMerge and Custom Attributes on classes

Tags: reflection, dll, ilmerge

I merged some dll files together and now my code that would find classes in one of the merged dll files cannot see the custom attributes I had on them. It can find all the classes fine but the attributes are missing. Any ideas how I can remedy this?

Edit: Further investigating show that the attributes are on the class but the Guid for the type is different than the original so GetCustomAttribute cannot find it.

Comment: which version of ILMerge, and with which argument are your running it?

Answer (score 0):

/copyattrs or /copyattrs:True.  You can also specify which attributes you want to use with the /attr:filename tag.

By default, it will use the attributes from the first assembly you merge in.